# ggplot2 axis label spacing when using two rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

When I run the following ggplot2 code, I get some odd spacing in my axis label (e.g., on the second row, it's as if ggplot2 tries to center the units, but then leaves the parentheses very far apart).

```
x <- c("x", "y")
y <- c(5, 10)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  ylab(bquote('Mean Subscribers\n('*km^2*')'))
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Any idea how I remove the space and center the axis label?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fr7R.png

Comment: I think you need `atop`, see linked post. It is for the legend, but works for axis labels, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution to using `bquote()` is to use {ggtext} which lets you use markdown syntax. I've found it much more straightforward to use, and much better at multi-line labels. For example:

```r
library(ggtext)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  ylab('Mean Subscribers<br>(km<sup>2</sup>)') +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_markdown())
```

[image: chart]